# How to create a custom Model in Qooxdoo? (for a list)

Tags: javascript, model, qooxdoo

I'm trying to make my own model but I don't know how.

I've been looking [at the ListControllerWithObjects demo](https://qooxdoo.org/qxl.demobrowser/#data%7EListControllerWithObjects.html) but I can only see:

```
var person = new demobrowser.demo.data.model.Person();
```

but don't show where it comes from or how is made. So this tutorial is not useful.

Why I want a custom model? I want to have custom class just for the model, to know the structure and to put custom methods in it.

I have: `[{a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 1, b: 9}];`

And I want to put it on a list, but using this

```
var model = this._model = new qx.data.Array([{id: 1, name: "Victor"}]);    
this._listController = new qx.data.controller.List(model, this._list, 'name');
```

doesn't work. The real error is SingleValueBinding:

> "Binding property " + propertyname + " of object " + source + " not
> possible: No event available. ";

It cannot find the event.

The error in the console:

> Uncaught qx.core.AssertionError: error

Comment: Cross-post from the qooxdoo mailing list, http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/How-to-create-my-own-model-I-cannot-find-tp7357709p7357709.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is here:

https://github.com/qooxdoo/qxl.demobrowser/blob/master/source/class/qxl/demobrowser/demo/data/model/Person.js

This file contains the definition of the missing Person class

Comment: Thanks... I can't confirm that it works, because I'm leaving qooxdoo, but I will accept this answer as it was what I wanted at the time.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.data.marshal.Json)

-> Your code should look like this:

```
var model = this._model = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel([{id: 1, name: "Victor"}]);    
this._listController = new qx.data.controller.List(model, this._list, 'name');
```

-> Mapping two model elements to the same property ("a" and "secondA"):

```
var data = [{a: 2, b: 4}, {secondA: 1, b: 9}];
var delegate = {
    getPropertyMapping : function(property, properties) {
        if (property === "secondA") {
            return "a";
        }

        return property;
    }
};

var marshaler = new qx.data.marshal.Json(delegate);
marshaler.toClass(data);
var model = marshaler.toModel(data);

this.assertEquals("2", model.toArray()[0].getA());
this.assertEquals("1", model.toArray()[1].getA());
```

Take at look [at my Playground example](http://goo.gl/QYqgC) or [the unit test of the JSON marshaler](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/test/data/marshal/Json.js) (search for "testGetPropertyMapping")

Comment: I don't understand how qooxdoo attributes a name to the model based on the model you gived in the example. What if I had 2 models with the same data but different names? how would it map them? strange, but thanks for your answer

Comment: The name of the model is based on the hash of the model keys. You can make use of the http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.data.marshal.IMarshalerDelegate to set an explicit model class based on the given properties (IMarshalerDelegate#getModelClass()).

Comment: can you give an example of how to really do, from the api I can't figure out how.. thanks ;)

Comment: @Totty I've updated my answer. Note, I didn't test the mapping stuff as I've no qx environment atm so it might need some tweaking ;-) but you should get the basic idea..

Comment: @Totty this playground example works as a charm (you have to open the "Log" pane, in order to see the output): http://goo.gl/QYqgC